# Is the usual enumeration of $\mathsf{PA}$ "minimal for consistency strength"?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, computability-theory, proof-theory

This question is about a technical imprecision which is easily avoidable but whose details I'd like to understand better. When we refer to "the consistency strength of $\mathsf{PA}$" (say) we aren't properly referring to $\mathsf{PA}$ as a set; rather, we care about the specific way in which $\mathsf{PA}$ is enumerated. "The set of sentences which $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves are $\mathsf{PA}$-axioms" is another way to define the same (hopefully!) set, but properly speaking it is equiconsistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

It occurs to me that I don't know whether the usual description of the $\mathsf{PA}$ axioms is optimal with respect to consistency strength. Below, let $(T_e)_{e\in\omega}$ be some appropriate enumeration of the c.e. theories. Suppose WLOG that $T_0$ is the usual c.e. presentation of $\mathsf{PA}$.

> **Question**: Is there an index $e$ such that ("extensionally") $T_e=\mathsf{PA}$ but $\mathsf{PA}+\mathsf{Con}(T_e)\not\vdash \mathsf{Con}(T_0)$?

One natural way to try to get a positive answer to this question is to enumerate the axioms of $\mathsf{PA}$ very slowly, waiting for contradictions, along the following lines: given a $\mathsf{PA}$-provably-total computable function $f$, let $T_f$ be the c.e. theory which enumerates the $n$th axiom of $\mathsf{PA}$ in the usual ($T_0$) sense iff there is no contradiction in $\mathsf{PA}$ using fewer than $f(n)$-many symbols. As long as $f$ is reasonably-fast-growing (say, dominating $n\mapsto 2^n$) it seems "$\mathsf{PA}$-believable" that $T_f$ detects a contradiction before falling prey to it.  On the other hand, I don't see how to show the consistency of $\mathsf{PA}+\mathsf{Con}(T_f)+\neg\mathsf{Con}(T_0)$ for any specific $f$.

([This older question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417484/proving-short-consistency-can-we-do-better-than-brute-force-search) seems thematically similar, but I don't actually see a concrete connection.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No (to the title), yes (to the question), see

Sy-David Friedman, Michael Rathjen, and Andreas Weiermann: *Slow consistency*, Annals of Pure and Applied Logic 164 (2013), no. 3, pp. 382–393, doi [10.1016/j.apal.2012.11.009](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2012.11.009).

The idea is that an axiom of usual PA of Gödel number $n$ is padded to length $f(n)$, where $f$ is a recursive function growing faster than all provably total recursive functions of PA (namely, $F_{\epsilon_0}$).

Comment: Oh that's a beautiful trick. Didn't occur to me at all! Out of curiosity, do you know if the line of attack I suggested can be made to work?

Comment: I can’t figure it out either way, it seems nontrivial.

Comment: I think at least it should hold that for any PA-provably total $f$, $\mathrm{Con}(T_f)$ implies slow consistency: my impression is that Lemma 3.5 in the paper should extend so that PA proves that if $F_{\epsilon_0}(x)$ exists, then there is no PA-proof of contradiction below $f(x)$.

Answer (score 7):

The *cautious enumeration* idea in my paper has some affinity with your suggestion.

- Joel David Hamkins, [Nonlinearity and illfoundedness in the hierarchy of large cardinal consistency strength](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.07445), arxiv:2208.07445.

The cautious enumeration of PA, denoted $\text{PA}^\circ$, enumerates the usual axioms of PA, unless a proof is found in PA of $\neg\text{Con}(\text{PA})$, in which case the enumeration stops. This is strictly weaker than PA in consistency strength, as argued in the paper, but in fact enumerates the very same axioms, assuming Con(PA+Con(PA)).

I argue in the paper that the cautious enumerations of our favorite theories, such as PA or ZFC, are natural, in the sense that this is what we would actually do if we were enumerating the theories and encountered such a proof along the way.

The cautious enumeration construction can be iterated, to find natural instances of ill-foundedness in the hierarchy of consistency strength.
$$\cdots < \text{ZFC}^{\circ\circ\circ} < \text{ZFC}^{\circ\circ} < \text{ZFC}^{\circ} <\text{ZFC}$$

Meanwhile, I prove that the stop-when-hopeless enumeration, which enumerates the usual axioms until such a point when the proof of a contradiction is observed, is equiconsistent with the original theory. The difference between this enumeration and the cautious enumeration is the difference between searching for a proof of a contradiction and searching for a proof that there is a proof of a contradiction. The latter gives lower consistency strength; the former does not.

Comment: Let me check that I understand the slightly vague “unless a proof is found” clause correctly: the $n$-th axiom of the “cautious” enumeration of $\mathsf{PA}$ is the same as the $n$-th axiom of $\mathsf{PA}$ provided no $k≤n$ encodes a proof of $¬\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$ in $\mathsf{PA}$ (and $0=0$ otherwise), is this correct?

Comment: Joel, Feferman introduced some time ago the following enumeration (that I will dub FA) of the axioms of PA; does it coincide with your notion of "cautious enumeration"? The axioms of FA are obtained by an infinite recursive process of “weeding out” applied to PA as follows: enumerate the proofs of PA until a proof of 0 = 1 is arrived, and then discard the largest axiom used in deriving 0 = 1; we then proceed to numerate proofs using only axioms of PA smaller than the one discarded. If we arrive at another proof of 0 = 1 from the reduced axiom system, we proceed in the same manner (continued).

Comment: (part 2 of the comment) By definition, FA consists of the axioms of PA that remain upon the completion of this recursive infinite process. Thus FA = PA in a sufficiently strong metatheory that can prove the consistency of PA.1 However, the consistency of FA is built into its definition and PA can readily verify this fact; thus the equality of FA and PA is not provable in PA even though this equality is provable in a sufficiently strong metatheory.

Comment: @AliEnayat What I’ve seen called the “Feferman provability predicate” includes axiom $x$ of PA if the theory axiomatized by $\{y\le x:y\text{ is an axiom of PA}\}$ is consistent. Is this the same as the infinite process? If so, this is rather different from Joel’s “cautious enumeration”. The Feferman enumeration has a properly $\Pi_1$ axiom set, and PA proves its own Feferman consistency. In contrast, Joel’s enumeration is an honest proof predicate of a recursive axiom set, and as such obeys all the usual Gödel theorems etc.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks for the clarification Emil.

Comment: Yes, my theory is c.e., but the Feferman theory is not. @Gro-Tsen,byes, that is correct.